# SimpleXMLElement Object back to XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Let's say you're getting the following response from an API call:

```
[OrderArray] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Order] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [OrderID] => etc...etc..<br>
```

How do I go about converting this back into well-formatted XML so that I can save each of my order arrays into their own separate file? (Please don't ask me why I have to perform this seemingly futile task.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$sxml is a simpleXMLElement

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
$doc->loadXML($sxml->asXML());
$xml = $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Why do you create a DOMDocument to wrap the XML from $sxml->asXML() ?

Comment: DOMDocument can create formatted xml.

Comment: You don't need all of this. You can turn a simplexml object [directly into a dom node](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php). So no need for saving and re-reading...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a SimpleXMLElement object, you can use the asXML method to get an XML string:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php